# Getting fatal error in object: unshallow <SHA> in gitlab pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-pipelines

I am trying to push a change to gitlab, but my gitlab pipeline is failing due to below error.

```
fatal error in object: unshallow <commit-hash>
```

I dont have access to the gitlab build pipeline, so cant update anything there. The only thing I know from the logs is that it says "Fetching changes with git depth set to 50".

Is there a way I can resolve this issue in my local git?

UPDATE: As per the answers, I tried changing the GIT_DEPTH to 760 instead of the default 50 and it worked. I had to increase it to a level that the unshallow commit comes in my clone. But I am not sure if this will resolve the issue permanently. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [issue 351976](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/351976), where the user had work around this issue by increasing the `GIT_DEPTH` of the secret detection job.

So check your [number of changes fetched during clone](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone), and check if there is a [shallow clone](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories/index.html#shallow-cloning):

> The following example makes the runner shallow clone to fetch only a given branch; it does not fetch any other branches nor tags.
>
> ```yaml
> variables:
>  GIT_DEPTH: 10
>
> test:
>  script:
>    - ls -al
> ```

Comment: Hey, I tried increasing the GIT_DEPTH to 100 but it still didnt work. I also tried finding the depth of the commit hash I am getting using the below command, but that is 752.
"git rev-list HEAD ^42c6ee9 --count"

Comment: @aru_sha4 Any chance you could do a full clone, instead of a shallow one?